# Java 8 collect vs reduce

Tags: java, java-8, reduce, collect

As known, when doing the accumulation, "reduce" always returns a new immutable object while "collect" will make changes on a mutable object.

However when I accidentally assign one method reference to both reduce and collect method, it compiles without any errors. Why?

Take a look at the following code:

```
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void testReduce() {

        BiFunction<MutableContainer,Long,MutableContainer> func =
            MutableContainer::reduce;

        // Why this can compile?
        BiConsumer<MutableContainer,Long> consume =
            MutableContainer::reduce;

        // correct way:
        //BiConsumer<MutableContainer,Long> consume =
        //  MutableContainer::collect;


        long param=10;

        MutableContainer container = new MutableContainer(0);


        consume.accept(container, param);
        // here prints "0",incorrect result,
        // because here we expect a mutable change instead of returning a immutable value
        System.out.println(container.getSum());

        MutableContainer newContainer = func.apply(container, param);
        System.out.println(newContainer.getSum());
    }
}

class MutableContainer {
    public MutableContainer(long sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    public long getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(long sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }

    private long sum;

    public MutableContainer reduce(long param) {
        return new MutableContainer(param);
    }

    public void collect(long param){
        this.setSum(param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the question reduces to this:  `BiConsumer` is a functional interface whose function is declared like this:

```
void accept(T t, U u)
```

You've given it a method reference with the correct parameters, but the wrong return type:

```
public MutableContainer reduce(long param) {
    return new MutableContainer(param);
}
```

[The `T` parameter is actually the `this` object when `reduce` is called, since `reduce` is an instance method and not a static method.  That's why the parameters are correct.]  The return type is `MutableContainer` and not `void`, however.  So the question is, why does the compiler accept it?

Intuitively, I think this is because a method reference is, more or less, equivalent to an anonymous class that looks like this:

```
new BiConsumer<MutableContainer,Long>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(MutableContainer t, Long u) {
         t.reduce(u);
     }
}
```

Note that `t.reduce(u)` will return a result.  However, the result is discarded.  Since it's OK to call a method with a result and discard the result, I think that, by extension, that's why it's OK to use a method reference where the method returns the result, for a functional interface whose method returns `void`.

Legalistically, I believe the reason is in [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).  This section is difficult and I don't fully understand it, but somewhere in this section it says

> If e is an exact method reference expression ... R<sub>2</sub> is
>   void.

where, if I read it correctly, R<sub>2</sub> is the result type of a functional interface method.  I think this is the clause that allows a non-void method reference to be used where a void method reference is expected.

(**Edit:** As Ismail pointed out in the comments, [JLS 15.13.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) may be the correct clause here; it talks about a method reference being congruent with a function type, and one of the conditions for this is that the result of the function type is `void`.)

Anyway, that should hopefully explain why it *compiles*.  Of course, the compiler can't always tell when you're doing something that will produce incorrect results.

Comment: I think [15.13.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2) is more relevant in this case -- "A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context [...] with a target type T [...] if [...] The result of the function type [of T] is void"

Comment: ok, i think the explanation is fairly clear. Not sure why this is accepted, since it will cause bug in most cases. Strong type checking should prevent this kind of bug.

Comment: You are correct on the motivation.  Just as you can invoke a method and discard the return type, you can convert a result-bearing method to a void-returning functional interface.  The previous commenter worries that this flexibility invites bugs, but the alternative was worse -- you couldn't even convert `aList::add` to a `Consumer`, since `add` returns something - and this would be really annoying, if you couldn't say `x.forEach(list::add)`!  Either solution was going to annoy someone.  This way was judged to be the lesser of evils.  And really, it wasn't even a close call.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Thanks for pointing this out.  I hadn't thought about "functions" whose main purpose is not to return a value but to make some important change, but that also return some kind of status, or an object for chaining, or something else.  Maybe some future language will make a distinction between those types of functions.  (A preliminary version of Ada distinguished between "functions" which were not allowed to have side-effects, and "value-returning procedures".  That didn't make it into the final 1983 standard.)